# What does KOMA stand for in "KOMA-Script"?

Tags: koma-script, naming

I could not find any hints to the acronym KOMA - maybe someone knows and can post his opinion.

It evolved from a bundle called "Script" - being the reason KOMA-Script classes start with "scr" followed by 5 letters of the class it is replacing in LaTeX I figured, e.g. scrartcl for a DIN adapted version of article.

There is no explicit wording about "5 letters" in scrguide. Where can I get a hold on the  "implementation (naming) guideline/rule" if there is any such?

Any hints warmly welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I seem to remember that the consensus is that it comes from the name of the developer: **Ko**hm, **Ma**rkus.
Sadly I can't find a source ATM.

In the history section of the `scrguide` he only states

> Ich will hier nicht näher auf die Wirren eingehen, die es um die offizielle Nachfolge
>   von Script gab und warum dieser neue Name gewählt wurde.

which basically means he doesn't want to expand on why it is named KOMA-Script.

Translation thanks to Steven B. Segletes:

> I will not dwell on the confusion [commotion?] that existed at the official successor of Scripts and why this new name was chosen here.

Comment: which google translate says means "I will not dwell on the confusion that existed at the official successor of Scripts and why this new name was chosen here."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I wouldn't translate it with "confusion", but I can't think of a better word. Surprisingly good translation.